# How to vary the contents in URL in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am having a URL in which it contains images and audio files. I am downloading the images and audio files to document directory by using the below code:

```
  // urlsArray contains the list of images and audio urls

 for(int i= 0 ;i<[urlsArrray count]; i++)
        {

        NSString *urlString = [urlsArrray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *escapedUrlString = [urlString             stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];
    NSData *fileData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *urlstring1 = [url absoluteString];
    NSArray *parts = [urlstring1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *fileName = [parts objectAtIndex:[parts count]-1];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:savedImagePath contents:fileData attributes:nil];

    NSLog(@"files Stored Path is %@",savedImagePath);
```

Now I want to seperate the images and audio files. I want to download images to document directory and audio files to cache directory.

Comment: You want to separate from this urlsArrray array or from documentdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following code to recognize the file whether it is image or audio file

```
CFStringRef fileExtension = (CFStringRef) [file pathExtension];
CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage)) NSLog(@"It's an image");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie)) NSLog(@"It's a movie");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeText)) NSLog(@"It's text");
else  NSLog(@"It's audio");
```

Comment: Sorry in my Xcode we are not getting UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);
 method, whenever we using this above method we got some error like: the function is invalid in c99. if u don't mind please say how to solve the above issue. @"V-Xtreme"

Comment: @ChandraSekhar:UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag is defined in the  MobileCoreServices.framework .You have to import it in your build phases .also import #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h> in your file

Answer (score 1):

OK if you separate from your array then do as below:

```
imagelist = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
videolist  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for(int i = 0;i<urlsArrray.count;i++)
   {
    id arrayElement = [fileArray  objectAtIndex:i];
    if([arrayElement rangeOfString:@".mp3" ].location !=NSNotFound)
    {
     [videolist addObject:arrayElement];
      NSLog(@"videolist..%@",videolist); 
    }
    else([arrayElement rangeOfString:@".png"].location !=NSNotFound)
    {
    [imagelist addObject:arrayElement];
    NSLog(@"imagelist..%@",imagelist);
    }
}
```

Comment: Here not necessary that the format of the files are fixed .It may be mp3,wav or any other.

Comment: imagelist & videolist are two nsmutable array declare both in .h file...

Comment: @V-Xtreme...we can also keep another options in and condition...

Comment: I dont understand ([arrayElement rangeOfString:@".mp3" ].location !=NSNotFound) this line.Can you please explain it ?

Comment: This mean that if in array type mp3 not found then it display what you want & if found then it add that type of file in videolist array...

Comment: sorry but thats not a generic solution. How many file format are you going to guess here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24962/discussion-between-v-xtreme-and-vishal)

Comment: I think ios only support mp3 format for audio...

Comment: No,iOS supports AAC (16 to 320 Kbps)
AIFF,AAC Protected (MP4 from iTunes Store),MP3 (16 to 320 Kbps),MP3,VBR,Audible (formats 2-4),WAV.