# Get only image files from directory

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am storing image file in cache directory . Later I want to get all image file list from cache directory. I am using following code to get all files.

```
[fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathForCacheDirectory error:&error]
```

How to separate image files from this. Image file can be any format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032541/nspredicate-endswith-multiple-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Store your supported image Extensions
NSArray *extensionList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jpg", @"jpeg", @"png", @"gif", @"bmp", nil];

// Grab the content Directory
NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathForCacheDirectory error:&error];

NSMutableArray *listOfImageFiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:0];

// Check for Images of supported type
for(NSString *filepath in contents){
    if ([extensionList containsObject:[filepath pathExtension]])
    {
        // Found Image File
        [listOfImageFiles addObject:filepath];
    }
}
NSLog(@"Lisf of Image Files : %@",listOfImageFiles);
```

Answer (score 1):

a brutal way is to enum all extensions you consider it to be an image.
a better way is using UTI, check this [Get the type of a file in Cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814463/get-the-type-of-a-file-in-cocoa)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter file using extensions.

```
 NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathForCacheDirectory error:&error];
    for(NSString *filepath in contents){
       if ([[filepath pathExtension] isEqualToString: @"png"]) {
            // Your code
        }
    }
```

Comment: in this case i need to check for all file extension. will it effect performance .

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope this will help.

```
 NSArray * contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:YOURPATH error:NULL];
    NSMutableArray * onlyImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (NSString * contentPath in contents) {
        NSString * lastPath = [contentPath pathExtension];

        if ([lastPath isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [lastPath isEqualToString:@"jpeg"] || [lastPath isEqualToString:@"png"] ||  /* any other */ ) {
            [onlyImages addObject:contentPath]; // only images
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See this & check:

```
CFStringRef fileExtension = (CFStringRef) [file pathExtension];
CFStringRef fileUTI = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, fileExtension, NULL);

if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeImage)) NSLog(@"It's an image");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeMovie)) NSLog(@"It's a movie");
else if (UTTypeConformsTo(fileUTI, kUTTypeText)) NSLog(@"It's text");
else  NSLog(@"It's audio");
```

Comment: Original Post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023064/how-to-vary-the-contents-in-url-in-ios/15023714#15023714